# C# DateTime Formatting Names

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

What is the name of this `DateTime` format:

```
Tue Apr 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Is there anyway I could detect this format in code?

The reason I am asking is that I have a function with `DateTime` parameter, which comes in different formats, and I would like to detect the format type or name; so that I could convert them accorddingly to the simple format of `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

The other second format I am getting is this: `2014-03-31T23:00:00.000Z`.

Many thanks.

**Edit**

I wrote this function to convert from `Tue Apr 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100` (GMT Daylight Time) to `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. This function fails when the input is of type `2014-03-31T23:00:00.000Z`.

I wonder how could possibly identify the type of parameter coming and convert accordingly?

```
public static DateTime ConvertDateObjectToDateTime(string dateToConvert)
{
    var value = new DateTime();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateToConvert))
    {
        int gmtIndex = dateToConvert.IndexOf("G", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);

        string newDate = dateToConvert.Substring(0, gmtIndex).Trim();

        value = DateTime.ParseExact(newDate, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return value;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: You have only these two format? `Tue Apr 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100` and `2014-03-31T23:00:00.000Z` ?

Comment: "GMT Daylight Time" is a non-sequitur to start with. Would you be happy enough to detect "stuff in brackets that I can ignore"?

Comment: Yes, I meant the function I mentioned receives two different formats into its DateTime parameter, and I'd like to convert both to the dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss. To do this, I think I need to identify the format first?

Comment: And why would you convert them to another string format? Why not *just* convert to a `DateTimeOffset` and keep it in that form?

Comment: Now you're really confusing me: "the function I mentioned receives two different formats into its DateTime parameter" makes no sense - if the parameter is of type `DateTime` then it doesn't *have* a format. It would really help if you'd make your question more concrete with code. I'd also strongly recommend avoiding converting to another string format if possible. There's a reason we have types other than string...

Comment: @JonSkeet because I want to insert this parameter in the database and it only seem to accept the final format I want to convert onto.

Comment: @t_plusplus: What's the type of the field in the database? If it's sensible (e.g. DateTime instead of VarChar), you should be able to use parameterized SQL and specify a `DateTimeOffset` value instead of a string value. Avoid string conversions where possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet the field-type in the database is datetime. I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: In that case you definitely shouldn't be converting it back to a string format. But you also shouldn't be cutting off "everything from G onwards" - I *suspect* that the value you're getting is the local time, in which case you should adjust it according to the offset in the string. But you should confirm that - it's not easy to tell from the sample string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is definitely UTC, however, the first *could* be UTC + offset or it could be Local + offset (it looks like the latter the more I examine it). The best tool you have in your armoury for parsing *specific* dates is the [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) method.

---

Based on your edit, I am concerned about the fact you are ignoring the timezone information. You are assuming at this point that the date is already UTC (which it may not be) and just parsing/treating it as is...

However, to answer your particular question

> I wonder how could possibly identify the type of parameter coming and convert accordingly?

You don't actually need to do that, `ParseExact` has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows you to specify multiple formats

```
value = DateTime.ParseExact(newDate, 
    new[] { "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'" }, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Comment: The first date is UTC + 1. So not UTC.

Comment: @JackHughes yeah so it's UTC with the offset provided. If there was no offset then it would be local time.

Comment: How do you know it's UTC with the offset provided? It may well be local time with the offset provided. That's one of the annoying things about date/time strings :(

Comment: @JonSkeet to be honest the more I look at it the more I think it *is* local with the offset. I updated my answer to just point that out.

Comment: @James I tried this code, and the compiler says it cannot resolve it.

Comment: @t_plusplus oops, should have been `ParseExact` not `TryParseExact` - although you should probably be using `TryParseExact` so your code doesn't throw an exception if the date can't be parsed (unless you specifically want that to happen).

Comment: @James thank you I tried it and the compiler error didn't happen. But I haven't actually tested it to see if it resolves the problem described above; because I have - in the meantime - changed my entire approach to it.